# Why I meet this exception when execute external program from Java

Tags: java, bash

This is my program and I run it on mac system.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("annotated_sentences.csv"));
    int count=0;
    scanner.nextLine();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        String split[]= line.split(",");
        String text = split[4];
        text=text.replace("&", "#");
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = run.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c",
            "curl --data text="+text+" https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/aida/service/disambiguate > /StanfordFile/"+count});

        count++;
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

I want to process like about 30000 lines but every time when it come to 335. The exception came out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at ProcessStanford.main(ProcessStanford.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 3 more
```

What's the reason?

Comment: Is this not a sign? `IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash": error=2, No such file or directory` <- seems like bash is not in the bin dir

Comment: Are you running under unix or windows?

Comment: I run it on Mac system

Comment: But the first 334 is ok..

Comment: There is no bash executable in the bin folder on your root.

Comment: But then? Rule 335 is calling `/bin/bash`?

Comment: I don't know. But if the first 334 times have no problem. Why at 335 will this error occur?

Comment: So "There is no bash executable in the bin folder on your root. " means that the "/bin/bash" was too busy at that time and caused this exception?

Comment: Can you log the whole statement of the Process ? Maybe this error occurs  because your ProcessBuilder build a wrong process.

Comment: You are not waiting for the bash processes to finish, so you are probably running in to some limit on the number of processes or something like that.

Comment: Yeah. For now it seems the problem is here.  I am thinking of some methods to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comments, I found the problem was because I opened too many process one time and the "bin/bash" couldn't handle them simultaneously. After several tests, I found it is safe to run 100 process within 2 minutes(because on average, the the speed of cloud service to handle the request is 1 request/2 minutes). So I just added one line `if(count%100==0)TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);` and the problem solved.